# How to use Microsoft Store SendRequestAsync method

Tags: uwp, store

UWP provides a `StoreRequestHelper` class with `SendRequestAsync` method

> as a flexible way to make new Store operations available to Universal
> Windows Platform (UWP) apps before a new version of the Windows SDK is
> released. You can use this method to send requests to the Store for
> new operations that do not yet have a corresponding API available in
> the latest release of the Windows SDK.

I would like to use this method to get some useful information from the store. For example the date when the user started the app trial.

Unfortunately it is not clear how to use this method. Documentation says it accepts a `requestKind` int parameter and `parametersAsJson` string parameter, but there are no details on what these should be (with the exception of something called a flight group).

Does anyone know how to use this method? I am specifically interested in getting the information about when the user started the trial so that I can implement my own app trial logic.

Comment: Please check this Send requests to the [Microsoft Store document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/send-requests-to-the-store)  that show the detail about how to use SendRequestAsync  method.

Comment: Hi, I have seen that document, but there is no sufficient details in there. What JSON parameters can I pass to the store? Where is this defined?

Comment: Above document contains  all the json parameter that could be used.

Comment: Are you saying that this can only be used for in app ratings and something called "flight groups"? Is this all?

Comment: Is "etc" defined anywhere? Documentation only talks of the first two. What else can be done with this?

Comment: Yep, it only contains those method you have seen.